# Compute $\sum_{k=1}^{n+3} {(k+1)^2}\binom {n}{k}x^{k+1}$

Tags: discrete-mathematics, binomial-theorem

Compute $\sum_{k=1}^{n+3} {(k+1)^2}\binom {n}{k}x^{k+1}$

Well, I believe I have somehow to get rid of $x$, maybe differentation. anyways, look at my stupidity: (Help is appreciated)

[image]

Comment: You can terminate at $k=n$ because $\binom{n}{k}=0$ when $k>n$.

Comment: The upper limit $n+3$ is a bit funny since $\binom{n}{k}=0$ when $k\gt n$. Start from $(1+x)^n=\sum \binom{n}{k}x^k$. Multliply by $x$, differentiate, multiply by $x$, differentiate. We more or less get your sum.

Comment: @AndréNicolas I got $(n-2)(n-1)nx^4(1+x)^{n-3} = (k+1)^2 \sum\binom {n}{k} x^{k+1}$. Is this the answer?

Comment: I have tp leave for a while, the right side is not right. Maybe will be able to check later.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could absorb one of the factors $(k+1)$ into $x$ by writing the expression as the derivative of some other expression with respect to $x,$ if only the power of $x$ were $k$ instead of $k+1$. So bring one factor $x$ to the left and rewrite your expression as

$$x\frac{d}{dx}\sum_{k=1}^n(k+1)\left({n\atop k}\right)x^{k+1}$$

and repeating the same trick

$$...=x\frac{d}{dx}x\frac{d}{dx}\sum_{k=1}^n\left({n\atop k}\right)x^{k+1}$$

now the binomial formula applies if we bring one more $x$ outside the sum

$$
...=x\frac{d}{dx}x\frac{d}{dx}x\sum_{k=1}^n\left({n\atop k}\right)x^{k}
=x\frac{d}{dx}x\frac{d}{dx}x((x+1)^n-1)
$$

Comment: I didn't study Integrations :(

Comment: Forget about integrations, call them the inverse of differentiations. I will adapt that part of the answer.

Comment: I got $(n-2)(n-1)nx^4(1+x)^{n-3} = (k+1)^2 \sum\binom {n}{k} * x^{k+1}$. Is this the answer?

Comment: How did you arrive at the expression on the left? It does not follow by working out the derivatives in my last line (that result, for sufficiently large $n,$ can never be divisible by $(x+1)$).

Comment: I've edited my post: http://i.stack.imgur.com/sSyb1.jpg (multiplied by x, differed, multiplied by x, differed, multiplied by x, and then added +1, because we need from k = 1.

Comment: Your derivations on the LHS (on your paper) are not entirely correct. For instance the derivative of $x(1+x)^n$ is not $x.n(1+x)^{n-1},$ that is just the first of two terms.

Comment: So I have to add $*2x$ in the first derivation?

Comment: Thank you!!!!!! Got it now.

Answer (score 0):

\begin{align}
f(x)&=\sum_{k=1}^{n+3} {(k+1)^2}\binom {n}{k}x^{k+1}\\
&=\sum_{k=1}^{n} {(k+1)^2}\binom {n}{k}x^{k+1}\\
\frac{f(x)}x&=\sum_{k=1}^{n} {(k+1)^2}\binom {n}{k}x^{k}\\
\int \frac{f(x)}xdx&=\sum_{k=1}^{n} {(k+1)}\binom {n}{k}x^{k+1}\\
\frac1x\int \frac{f(x)}xdx&=\sum_{k=1}^{n} {(k+1)}\binom {n}{k}x^{k}\\
\int\left(\frac1x\int \frac{f(x)}xdx\right)dx&=\sum_{k=1}^{n} {}\binom {n}{k}x^{k+1}\\
&=x\left((1+x)^n-1\right)\\
\frac1x\int \frac{f(x)}xdx&=\left((1+x)^n-1\right)+nx(1+x)^{n-1}-1\\
\int \frac{f(x)}xdx&=x\left((1+x)^n-1\right)+nx^2(1+x)^{n-1}-x\\
\frac{f(x)}x&=x\left((1+x)^n-1\right)+nx^2(1+x)^{n-1}-x+2nx(1+x)^{n-1}+(n-1)nx^2(1+x)^{n-1}-1\\
&=x\left((1+x)^n-1\right)+n(x^2+2x+n-1)(1+x)^{n-1}-x-1\\
f(x)&=x^2\left((1+x)^n-1\right)+nx(x^2+2x+n-1)(1+x)^{n-1}-x^2-x\\
f(1)&=2^n-1+n(n+2)2^{n-1}-2=(n^2+2n+2)2^{n-1}-3\\
&=\sum_{k=1}^{n} {(k+1)^2}\binom {n}{k}x^{k+1}
\end{align}

Comment: I didn't study Integrations :(